# Delete SKU in .phtml file

Tags: template, sku

i want to disable SKU in .phtml-file and i don't know where i can find the phtml-file that includes SKU. Please can somebody tell me whats the path to the file that includes phtml with SKU.
Or if you have suggestion to delete it easier let me know, but in any case i want to know where the .phtml-file is, that include SKU. Path hints on developer doesn't show!

Thanks

Comment: do you want to disable sku from frontend to display from all pages?

Comment: from all pages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your template.

Try looking into `catalog/product/view.phtml`.

Search for something like `$_product->getSku()`.

Comment: great man thats it!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Just set this as correct answer and enjoy your Magento ;)

Answer (score 1):

Log in to admin

Go to `Catalog > attribute > Manage attribute`

find attribute with name `sku`

click on sku attribute row.

**Visible on Product View Page on Front-end select "No" also Used in Product Listing "No".**

Clear cache.

refresh all pages.

**Note:- Don't edit or delete from core files or .phtml is better idea if no need.**

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: This doesn't helped me i don't know why, i comment it out on view.phtml, thanks a lot!

Comment: you have to clear cache and reindex data from admin and check it.

Comment: I undestand, but it was checked as disabled before i changed anything. i mean it was set on NO, as you described!

Comment: ok dude...!!! but changing in templates is bed habit. i hope you understand.

Comment: Yes i understand, thats why i tried yours first. Thanks!